# System.loadLibrary() not working in some instances

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am making a cocos2d-x game and I was experiencing some weird behavior im not sure if its normal or whats going on but this is whats happening, so the `AppActivity.java` class extends `Cocos2dxActivity.java` class. I did not have to call `System.loadLibrary("MyGame");` in my `AppActivity.java` class since it is being called in `Cocos2dxActivity.java`.  But this is what happens if I do a normal declaration like this

```
private native String invokeNativeString();
```

everything works fine, but then I try to declare this directly underneath and I receive this error

```
String ami = new String(invokeNativeString());
```

And got errors:

```
05-01 09:11:27.250 10135-10135/com.izzyjmachado.spaceball E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.izzyjmachado.spaceball, PID: 10135
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity.invokeNativeString() (tried Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_invokeNativeString and Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_invokeNativeString__)
```

Why is it working when I declare a normal native string but when I use the method inside the declaration of a string its not finding the method ?

I was able to resolve this by calling this in my `AppActivity` class but I feel like it should be working with out having to call `loadLibrary` in my `appActivity` class since its already being called in `Cocos2dxActivity` and `appActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity` ? thanks to any help you guys can give me

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("MyGame");
}
```

Comment: when I move the string with base64 to inside the onCreate method everything works fine, still would like to know why it doesn't work declaring it with my other global variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your activity calls `super.onCreate()` early in its `onCreate()`. *Just to make it clear:* This is how it should be called, you made no mistake.

***But.*** Cocos2dxActivity authors chose to load the native library during `onCreate()`. They had a good reason to make this decision: it allowed them to extract **android.app.lib_name** from your package, and this way to choose the correct library.

The JNI tutorials usually recommend to load the native libraries in `static {}` block. The latter is a safer practice (e.g. it resolves your problem with field initialization), but it has its own drawbacks, too.

The bottom line, you can move initialization of the **ami** field into `AppActivity.onCreate()`, if you like this way, or you can use the `static` block in your **AppActivity**, if you prefer. The end user will not really notice the difference.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer , now it all makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It seems you tried to call native function while native library is not yet loaded.

Comment: but it works when I call "private native String invokeNativeString();" and I put this declaration "String ami = new String(Base64.decode(invokeNativeString(),Base64.DEFAULT));" in the same spot so I don't think that is the problem